# What does "Remove disks or other media" mean in GRUB rescue?

Tags: boot, usb, uefi

Every time I turn my pc on with a USB plugged in, I get this message:

```
Remove disks or other media.
Press any key to restart
```

I set my BIOS boot order to boot the USB first.

Why does that error appear?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output of `gdisk /dev/sdX` where /dev/sdX is the USB device in question.

Comment: Elder Geek: I cant get the output of  `gdisk` because i cant access the ubuntu partition. And this may sound like a noob question, but why? Im just asking because im kinda new

Comment: Please [edit] your question to indicate you can no longer boot using UEFI or clarify what you mean. I thought I understood you but I guess it's still unclear to me.

Comment: No no... I CAN boot from UEFI mode. Im just asking: why does that error appear? And with "error" i mean `Remove disks or other media. Press any key to restart `.

Comment: The "error" means - Remove disks or other media. Press any key to restart

Comment: That error looks like it's from the computer itself. Is it actually in GRUB rescue?

Answer (score 1):

The "error" means exactly what it says. `Remove disks or other media. Press any key to restart.` It occurs because the system is trying to boot from non-bootable media. Likely your boot order is wrong in the BIOS or your "bootable" media is improperly prepared or has a corrupt or incorrect MBR or PBR

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced the problem OP posted attempting to install Ubuntu 16.04 onto Samsung Series 7 Chronos. I went into the BIOS settings and enabled UEFI. This appears to has resolved the issue for me, and the Ubuntu install is sailing along.